# Is there a way to have sidescrolloff behave differently depending if I am end of a line?

Tags: scrolling, formatting

I work in two broadly different ways in vim (that are relevant to this question):

1. I am writing text or markdown-formatted content, writing paragraphs of text. In this case I am generally writing new content, so it is most elegant for `sidescrolloff` to be set to 0, otherwise the window content jumps left when I near the end of a line.
2. I am editing existing programming code (e.g. python), which may have line lengths longer than it 'should' have (e.g. longer than `textwidth`). In this case I don't want to reformat those lines - I want to work with them at the length they are. In this case it is more elegant if `sidescrolloff` is, for example, 20, so that when my cursor gets nearer the end of the window/line on the right I can see the text to the right more clearly.

Is there an elegant way to set the value of `sidescrolloff` differently depending if I am appending at the end of a line versus in the middle of it (i.e. the middle of the content)? Or perhaps a way to set it depending if I am in insert mode or normal mode?

Alternatively, are there any other elegant solutions to my problem?

In both these cases I use `textwidth=78` and `nowrap`.

Comment: Have you looked into using modelines or filetypes?

Answer (score 2):

The `'sidescrolloff'` option so far is a global option; i.e. it can have only one fixed value. However, you can use `:autocmd`s to dynamically switch its value based on the current buffer's filetype (Markdown vs. Python), or syntax (inside comments vs. inside code (can use my [OnSyntaxChange plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4085) for that)), or use the `CursorMoved[I]` events (for inserting in the middle vs. end).

Comment: thanks for the response, sorry for the slow reply. If I went for the lo-fi autocmd approach, i.e. `autocmd FileType markdown set sidescrolloff=0`, doesn't that require me to then create a corresponding autocmd for every other filetype I use (since it's a global option). Is there a way to create an autocmd that only applies for files that are *not* type XYZ?

Comment: Yes, you can do that with a global autocmd and a conditional: `autocmd FileType * if &filetype != 'markdown' | set sidescrolloff=3 | endif`; I would then combine this with the other (positive) one via `else`.